# Clearing Arduino's serial buffer

Tags: arduino

i have a simple arduino code:

```
void loop()
{
  if serial.available
  {
    c = serial.read();
    if (c == 'a')
    {
      blinkled();
    }
    else
      offled();
  }
}
```

it should glow the led if i send a character 'a'.
and it shld go off when i dont give anything when the loop goes into the next itration.

but once i give 'a'. it starts glowing and never goes off.

is it reading the char 'a' from the buffer? 
if so then how to clear it ?

Serial.flush() not working.

any ideas please.
am new to arduino.
sorry if its silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put your offled function INSIDE the Serial.available() path. You could only turn it off by Serial.available() being true and you pushing a different character so it reads something other than 'a'

Unfortunately the example above makes the same mistake.

Construct it so that the led turns off outside that if statement

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        char received = Serial.read();
        inData += received; 

        // Process message when new line character is received
        if (received == '\n')
        {
            Serial.print("Arduino Received: ");
            Serial.print(inData);

            // You can put some if and else here to process the message juste like that:

            if(inData == "a\n"){ // DON'T forget to add "\n" at the end of the string.
              Serial.println("OK, I'll blink now.");
              blinkled();
            }
            else if (inData == "b\n") {
              offled();
            }   

            inData = ""; // to flush the value.
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** I've modified my answer based on the correct answer.

Comment: Its a bad idea to wait on the loop, you could do `if(Serial.available() > 0)` then without that `inData += received` mumbo jumbo you could just do `inData = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n')` to read until the `\n`

Comment: Yes, both work. Regarding `readBytesUntil`, I'm not sure it was available at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```
void loop()
{
    offled();    
    char c = Serial.read();
    while (Serial.available() <= 0 || c != 'a') { 
        blinkled();      
    }
}
```